# HttpOnly cookie does not work in java + spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat, cookies

I am using spring boot and spring security and I am trying to generate an httpOnly cookie after the user authentication.
After the user has successfully been authenticated I want to generate a token in the `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` and return it as an httpOnly cookie. 
I tried different approach but I was not able to get the cookie as httpOnly. Herse's the snippet of code supposed to set the cookie:

```
import javax.servlet.http.Cookie;
public class AuthSecurityhandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {

public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException {
    String jwt = tokenManagerService.generateAccessToken(authentication.getPrincipal());
    Cookie cookie = new Cookie("token", jwt);
    cookie.setHttpOnly(true);
    response.addCokie(cookie);
}
}
```

The above example set a cookie but it is not httpOnly.

I also tried:

```
Cookie cookie=new Cookie("token", jwt);
cookie.setPath(";Path=/; HttpOnly");
response.addCookie(cookie);
```

This gives me the exception "An invalid path [; Path=/;httpOnly]" was specified for this cookie.

The value of the cookie is a jwt token base64 url encoded.
I am using spring boot 2.2.2 and here I am on the Zuul gateway.
I am using an embedded instance of Tomcat.
I see that the session cookie created automatically by spring after authentication does have this flag on. So I can't figure out why the flag doesn't work setting it manually.
Does anyone know how to enable this flag?

Comment: Maybe post the Set-Cookie header returned by the server, and mention a bit more context of your method (full package of the Cookie  and response variables, type of bean, ..) to help debuggin

Comment: Hello, I want to create the cookie after the authentication in the AutenticationSuccessHandler. So the user post the credentials, and after authentication the handler is executed and there I try to create the cookie. In the first case using setHttpOnly(true) I receive "set-cookie: jwt=xxx.yyy.zzz" so the JWT follows that notation. In the second case I only have an exception as reported above

Comment: this is weird. What class is `response`, and what type of service is running the snippset you posted?

Comment: @cghislai I added a little bit more context in my post, can you tell me if this is helpful? The cookie is generated in the AuthenticationSuccessHandler which is managed by spring-security after the user authentication.

Comment: For cookie.setHttpOnly() I have figured out that only starting from tomcat servlet 3.0 it is working. At the end I opted for response.addHeader("Set-Cookie", "token=" + jwt + "; HttpOnly"); adding the cookie manually works fine for me.